# Misunderstanding return method's behavior

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't understand why following code executes two different return line:

```
public static QuotazioneInfo load(QuotazioneInfo quotazione) {
    QuotazioneInfo quotazioneInfoCached = quotazioniCached.get(quotazione.getTitolo());
    if(quotazioneInfoCached != null){
        long ultimoAggiornamento = new Date().getTime() - lastUpdated.get(quotazione.getTitolo()).getTime();
        long DIECI_MINUTI = 600000;
        if(ultimoAggiornamento < DIECI_MINUTI)
            return quotazioneInfoCached; <-- Debugger passing HERE
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        // [cut]
        lastUpdated.put(quotazione.getTitolo(), new Date());
        quotazioniCached.put(quotazione.getTitolo(), quotazione);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return quotazione; <-- And also HERE
}
```

Using debugger I see that will execute both return lines code, but the second returns a mistaken value. Why happens this?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't execute both return statements. If it executes the first, it won't execute the second.

Comment: it is an impression of the java debugger due to the differences between the java bytecode and the *android* bytecode

Comment: The issue is that the java debugger "pass" throught the second one but it is not really executting it.

Comment: BTW: `new Date().getTime()` is easier written as `System.currentTimeMillis()`; and `600000` is more readably written as `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10)`.

Comment: Thanks all, I added caching later, before I didn't use return value, but just the object passed by reference. So in the caller class I used the object referenced in arguments instead of the returned object. I'm sorry for this question, thanks again.